# powershell to edit localstate file in JSON

Tags: json, powershell, google-chrome

I am working editing the localstate file of chrome as part of logon script.

Currently its - `{"browser":{"last_redirect_origin":""}`

I need to change it for `{"browser":{"enabled_labs_expirements":["allow-insecure-localhost"], "last_redirect_origin":""})`

I tried below -

```
    $jsonFilePath = 'file.json'
    $jsonContent  = Get-Content -Path $jsonFilePath
    $jsonAsPsObjects = $jsonContent | ConvertFrom-Json
    $newResources = @("enabled_labs_expirments"::"[allow-insecure-localhost]")
    $newResources | ForEach-Object -Process { $jsonAsPsObjects.Resource += $_ }
    $jsonAsPsObjects | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -Path $jsonFilePath
```

Its not working. Please help.

Below is JSON File

```
{"browser":{"last_redirect_origin":""},"hardware_acceleration_mode_previous":true,"legacy":{"profile":{"name":{"migrated":true}}},"network_time":{"network_time_mapping":{"local":1.597665088413799e+12,"network":1.597665078e+12,"ticks":418704820059.0,"uncertainty":1486624.0}},"password_manager":{"os_password_blank":false,"os_password_last_changed":"0"},"plugins":{"metadata":{"adobe-flash-player":{"displayurl":true,"group_name_matcher":"*Shockwave Flash*","help_url":"https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=plugin_flash","lang":"en-US","mime_types":["application/futuresplash","application/x-shockwave-flash"],"name":"Adobe Flash Player","url":"https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784","versions":[{"reference":"https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/flash-player/apsb17-32.html","status":"requires_authorization","version":"27.0.0.170"}]},"adobe-reader":{"displayurl":true,"group_name_matcher":"*Adobe Acrobat*","help_url":"https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=plugin_pdf","lang":"en-US","mime_types":["application/pdf","application/vnd.adobe.x-mars","application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml","application/vnd.adobe.xfd+xml","application/vnd.adobe.xfdf","application/vnd.fdf"],"name":"Adobe Reader","url":"https://get.adobe.com/reader/","versions":[{"reference":"https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/reader/apsb14-28.html","status":"requires_authorization","version":"10.1.13"},{"status":"out_of_date","version":"11"},{"reference":"https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/reader/apsb14-28.html","status":"requires_authorization","version":"11.0.10"}]},"adobe-shockwave":{"group_name_matcher":"*Shockwave for Director*","help_url":"https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=plugin_shockwave","lang":"en-US","mime_types":["application/x-director"],"name":"Adobe Shockwave Player","url":"http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/shockwave/default/english/win95nt/latest/Shockwave_Installer_Slim.exe","versions":[{"reference":"https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/shockwave/apsb14-10.html","status":"requires_authorization","version":"12.1.0.150"}]},"apple-quicktime":{"group_name_matcher":"*QuickTime Plug-in*","help_url":"https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=plugin_quicktime","lang":"en-US","mime_types":["application/sdp","application/x-mpeg","application/x-rtsp","application/x-sdp","audio/3ggp","audio/3ggp2","audio/aac","audio/ac3","audio/aiff","audio/amr","audio/basic","audio/mid","audio/midi","audio/mp4","audio/mpeg","audio/vnd.qcelp","audio/wav","audio/x-aac","audio/x-ac3","audio/x-aiff","audio/x-caf","audio/x-gsm","audio/x-m4a","audio/x-m4b","audio/x-m4p","audio/x-midi","audio/x-mpeg","audio/x-wav","image/jp2","image/jpeg2000","image/jpeg2000-image","image/pict","image/png","image/x-jpeg2000-image","image/x-macpaint","image/x-pict","image/x-png","image/x-quicktime","image/x-sgi","image/x-targa","video/3ggp","video/3ggp2","video/flc","video/mp4","video/mpeg","video/quicktime","video/sd-video","video/x-m4v","video/x-mpeg"],"name":"QuickTime Player","url":"http://appldnld.apple.com/QuickTime/041-3089.20111026.Sxpr4/QuickTimeInstaller.exe","versions":[{"reference":"http://support.apple.com/kb/HT203092","status":"requires_authorization","version":"7.7.6"}]},"chromium-pdf":{"group_name_matcher":"*Chromium PDF Viewer*","mime_types":[],"name":"Chromium PDF Viewer","versions":[{"comment":"Chromium PDF Viewer has no version information.","status":"fully_trusted","version":"0"}]},"chromium-pdf-plugin":{"group_name_matcher":"*Chromium PDF Plugin*","mime_types":[],"name":"Chromium PDF Plugin","versions":[{"comment":"Chromium PDF Plugin has no version information.","status":"fully_trusted","version":"0"}]},"divx-player":{"group_name_matcher":"*DivX Web Player*","help_url":"https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=plugin_divx","lang":"en-US","mime_types":["video/divx","video/x-matroska"],"name":"DivX Web Player","url":"http://download.divx.com/player/divxdotcom/DivXWebPlayerInstaller.exe","versions":[{"status":"requires_authorization","version":"1.4.3.4"}]},"facebook-video-calling":{"group_name_matcher":"*Facebook Video*","lang":"en-US","mime_types":["application/skypesdk-plugin"],"name":"Facebook Video Calling","url":"https://www.facebook.com/chat/video/videocalldownload.php","versions":[{"comment":"We do not track version information for the Facebook Video Calling Plugin.","status":"requires_authorization","version":"0"}]},"google-chrome-pdf":{"group_name_matcher":"*Chrome PDF Viewer*","mime_types":[],"name":"Chrome PDF Viewer","versions":[{"comment":"Google Chrome PDF Viewer has no version information.","status":"fully_trusted","version":"0"}]},"google-chrome-pdf-plugin":{"group_name_matcher":"*Chrome PDF Plugin*","mime_types":[],"name":"Chrome PDF Plugin","versions":[{"comment":"Google Chrome PDF Plugin has no version information.","status":"fully_trusted","version":"0"}]},"google-earth":{"group_name_matcher":"*Google Earth*","lang":"en-US","mime_types":["application/geplugin"],"name":"Google Earth","url":"http://www.google.com/earth/explore/products/plugin.html","versions":[{"comment":"We do not track version information for the Google Earth Plugin.","status":"requires_authorization","version":"0"}]},"google-talk":{"group_name_matcher":"*Google Talk*","mime_types":[],"name":"Google Talk","versions":[{"comment":"'Google Talk Plugin' and 'Google Talk Plugin Video Accelerator' use two completely different versioning schemes, so we can't define a minimum version.","status":"requires_authorization","version":"0"}]},"google-update":{"group_name_matcher":"Google Update","mime-types":[],"name":"Google Update","versions":[{"comment":"Google Update plugin is versioned but kept automatically up to date","status":"requires_authorization","version":"0"}]},"ibm-java-runtime-environment":{"group_name_matcher":"*IBM*Java*","mime_types":["application/x-java-applet","application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.7.0_05","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.3","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.3","application/x-java-applet;version=1.3.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.5","application/x-java-applet;version=1.6","application/x-java-applet;version=1.7","application/x-java-bean","application/x-java-bean;jpi-version=1.7.0_05","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.3","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.3","application/x-java-bean;version=1.3.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.5","application/x-java-bean;version=1.6","application/x-java-bean;version=1.7","application/x-java-vm","application/x-java-vm-npruntime"],"name":"IBM Java","versions":[]},"java-runtime-environment":{"displayurl":true,"group_name_matcher":"Java*","help_url":"https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=plugin_java","lang":"en-US","mime_types":["application/x-java-applet","application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.7.0_05","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.3","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.3","application/x-java-applet;version=1.3.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.5","application/x-java-applet;version=1.6","application/x-java-applet;version=1.7","application/x-java-bean","application/x-java-bean;jpi-version=1.7.0_05","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.3","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.3","application/x-java-bean;version=1.3.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.5","application/x-java-bean;version=1.6","application/x-java-bean;version=1.7","application/x-java-vm","application/x-java-vm-npruntime"],"name":"Java(TM)","url":"http://java.com/download","versions":[{"comment":"Java SE 7u45","status":"requires_authorization","version":"10.45"}]},"microsoft-office":{"group_name_matcher":"*Microsoft Office*","mime_types":[],"name":"Microsoft Office","versions":[{"comment":"Microsoft Office has no version information.","status":"requires_authorization","version":"0"}]},"nvidia-3d":{"group_name_matcher":"*NVIDIA 3D*","mime_types":[],"name":"NVIDIA 3D","versions":[{"comment":"NVidia 3D has no version information.","status":"requires_authorization","version":"0"}]},"realplayer":{"group_name_matcher":"*RealPlayer*","help_url":"https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=plugin_real","lang":"en-US","mime_types":["audio/vnd.rn-realaudio","video/vnd.rn-realvideo","audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin","audio/x-pn-realaudio"],"name":"RealPlayer","url":"http://forms.real.com/real/realone/download.html?type=rpsp_us","versions":[{"reference":"http://service.real.com/realplayer/security/02062012_player/en/","status":"requires_authorization","version":"15.0.2.71"}]},"silverlight":{"group_name_matcher":"*Silverlight*","lang":"en-US","mime_types":["application/x-silverlight","application/x-silverlight-2"],"name":"Silverlight","url":"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156","versions":[{"reference":"https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3056819","status":"requires_authorization","version":"5.1.40416.0"}]},"windows-media-player":{"displayurl":true,"group_name_matcher":"*Windows Media Player*","help_url":"https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=plugin_wmp","lang":"en-US","mime_types":[],"name":"Windows Media Player","url":"http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/wmp-extension-for-chrome"},"x-version":40},"resource_cache_update":"1597641724.70047"},"policy":{"last_statistics_update":"13242115235005268"},"profile":{"info_cache":{"Default":{"active_time":1597665944.342043,"avatar_icon":"chrome://theme/IDR_PROFILE_AVATAR_26","background_apps":false,"gaia_given_name":"user","gaia_id":"100944961334535043745","gaia_name":"user S","is_consented_primary_account":false,"is_ephemeral":false,"is_omitted_from_profile_list":false,"is_using_default_avatar":true,"is_using_default_name":true,"managed_user_id":"","metrics_bucket_index":1,"name":"Person 1","shortcut_name":"user","user_name":"user.ec@gmail.com"}},"last_active_profiles":["Default"],"last_used":"Default","metrics":{"next_bucket_index":2}},"rappor":{"cohort_seed":490,"last_daily_sample":"13242115265357098","secret":"Qp+yQZ1Pc7rPQgy30x7LE1yJXe9vUJI5otb1EPPcGOIb5Q/sednSUxtG0Wrq2OVv"},"shutdown":{"num_processes":0,"num_processes_slow":0,"type":0},"software_reporter":{"last_time_triggered":"13241521682947060"},"subresource_filter":{"ruleset_version":{"checksum":2096522732,"content":"9.15.1","format":26}},"tab_stats":{"last_daily_sample":"13242115264368018","max_tabs_per_window":8,"total_tab_count_max":13,"window_count_max":2},"ukm":{"persisted_logs":[]},"uninstall_metrics":{"installation_date2":"1597047496","launch_count":"9","page_load_count":"1571","uptime_sec":"140404"},"updateclientdata":{"apps":{"aemomkdncapdnfajjbbcbdebjljbpmpj":{"cohort":"","cohortname":"","dlrc":4977,"pf":"d0ea1c1f-7e15-4320-b8fc-11840682f8bc"},"bklopemakmnopmghhmccadeonafabnal":{"cohort":"1:swl:","cohorthint":"Auto","cohortname":"Auto","dlrc":4977,"pf":"98201a49-ce3a-40aa-944d-95e2dce24e48"},"ehgidpndbllacpjalkiimkbadgjfnnmc":{"cohort":"1:ofl:","cohorthint":"stable64","cohortname":"stable64","dlrc":4977,"pf":"ad093a04-e7e9-49c7-9c5d-d9272d8797f0"},"gcmjkmgdlgnkkcocmoeiminaijmmjnii":{"cohort":"1:bm1:w43@0.01,w6l@0.01","cohorthint":"M54ToM99","cohortname":"M54ToM99","dlrc":4977,"pf":"a7666d1f-cadc-4f4c-8ae0-41df352ba357"},"giekcmmlnklenlaomppkphknjmnnpneh":{"cohort":"1:j5l:","cohorthint":"Auto","cohortname":"Auto","dlrc":4977,"pf":"8204f359-895f-484e-9123-15d327254cf2"},"gkmgaooipdjhmangpemjhigmamcehddo":{"cohort":"1:pw3:","cohorthint":"Stable","cohortname":"Stable","dlrc":4977,"pf":"57f06ecf-acbc-43d7-ac09-58d7829e962a"},"hfnkpimlhhgieaddgfemjhofmfblmnib":{"cohort":"1:jcl:","cohorthint":"Auto","cohortname":"Auto","dlrc":4977,"pf":"c25e7294-47af-437f-beec-f757d622615e"},"hnimpnehoodheedghdeeijklkeaacbdc":{"cohort":"","cohortname":"","dlrc":4977,"pf":"9155cb53-48d0-45f2-8223-71d8b8b592b1"},"ihnlcenocehgdaegdmhbidjhnhdchfmm":{"cohort":"","cohortname":"","dlrc":4977,"pf":"1b754ffe-498b-4c16-a516-b316953c17a7"},"jflookgnkcckhobaglndicnbbgbonegd":{"cohort":"1:s7x:","cohorthint":"Auto","cohortname":"Auto","dlrc":4977,"pf":"42e56fa9-2060-4f38-b338-c10d5db2bf90"},"khaoiebndkojlmppeemjhbpbandiljpe":{"cohort":"1:cux:","cohorthint":"Auto","cohortname":"Auto","dlrc":4977,"pf":"8a9c0058-458c-4713-9331-e845707d9c06"},"llkgjffcdpffmhiakmfcdcblohccpfmo":{"cohort":"","cohortname":"","dlrc":4977,"pf":"f0a662f9-fa41-40b3-a0ee-bb3fe47507c7"},"mimojjlkmoijpicakmndhoigimigcmbb":{"cohort":"1:d0j:","cohorthint":"Chrome [M50+]","cohortname":"Chrome [M50+]","dlrc":4977,"pf":"1dee7ded-68f3-4c6b-a0ac-57778a995175"},"oimompecagnajdejgnnjijobebaeigek":{"cohort":"","cohortname":"","dlrc":4977,"pf":"2b72d762-ccd5-4878-812e-a66cc7c50b72"}}},"user_experience_metrics":{"client_id2":"4b7a2a15-69af-4ea8-937d-6ab787819c60","client_id_timestamp":"1597047496","initial_logs2":[],"last_seen":{"BrowserMetrics":"13242115324801746","CrashpadMetrics":"13241772787534078","SetupMetrics":"13229717183604685"},"low_entropy_source3":3226,"machine_id":994252,"ongoing_logs2":[],"session_id":8,"stability":{"breakpad_registration_fail":0,"breakpad_registration_ok":0,"browser_last_live_timestamp":"13242139588375155","child_process_crash_count":0,"crash_count":0,"debugger_not_present":0,"debugger_present":0,"deferred_count":0,"discard_count":0,"exited_cleanly":false,"extension_renderer_crash_count":0,"extension_renderer_failed_launch_count":0,"extension_renderer_launch_count":2,"gpu_crash_count":0,"incomplete_session_end_count":0,"launch_count":0,"page_load_count":12,"plugin_stats2":[],"renderer_crash_count":0,"renderer_failed_launch_count":0,"renderer_hang_count":0,"renderer_launch_count":1,"saved_system_profile":"*******,"saved_system_profile_hash":"D862A420C10D980361A7434C62554A703FE0B3F5","session_end_completed":true,"stats_buildtime":"1579128889","stats_version":"79.0.3945.130-64","system_crash_count":0,"version_mismatch_count":0}},"variations_compressed_seed":"*******","variations_seed_date":"13242138678000000","variations_seed_signature":"********","was":{"restarted":false}}
```

Comment: `@("enabled_labs_expirments":["allow-insecure-localhost"])` is not valid PowerShell, and in the next-to-last line you attempt to assign to a `Resource` property, but the sample json shown above doesn't contain any `Resource` keys. Can you share the full input json file?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Attaching the input JSON file. I have updated the powershell.

Comment: @goe What you've posted is not valid JSON